# ColdFusion cfhttp request body not being sent to NodeJS server

Tags: coldfusion, cfhttp

I'm trying to send a cfhttp request with a body content to a NodeJS server, but it's being sent empty.

ColdFusion:

```
<cfset data = {
    test: "abc",
    id: 5
} />
<cfhttp result="test" method="GET" url="http://myNodeJSServer.com/test">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json" />
    <cfhttpparam type="body" value="#serializeJSON(data)#" />
</cfhttp>

<cfdump var="#test#" />
```

In the NodeJS I check the body:

```
exports.test = async (req, res, next) => {
   console.log(req.body);
}
```

This log is empty even though I am sending body data in the CF request. Am I using the cfhttp wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try `method="POST"` in `cfhttp`?

Comment: No because the method where I'm sending data is "GET", not "POST". I just tried to make sure, it returns 404

Comment: What happens when you hit the same URL from a browser? Are you sure you are looking in the correct place for the `console.log()` output?

Comment: @Miguel-F, yes, when I use the same url in the browser, I can see the log

Comment: I change the NodeJS to be POST and send the ColdFusion request as POST and it worked. Does ColdFusion just allow sending body data in a POST request, not GET? It's odd

Comment: The semantics for GET requests with a body is undefined, unlike POST https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body#983458